# How do I hide the select software site portion of the UI on the Eclipse Install New Software dialog in my RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, p2

I found documentation that states I can hide some of the UI elements in the Install New Software dialog in an Eclipse RCP application.

It's all described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application#Configuring_the_p2_UI).

I want my RCP application (based on Eclipse 3.7) to hide the available software sites just like the RCP Mail example app does, so I've implemented my RCP application using this example.  But, it's not working.

I've even gone so far as to import the RCP Mail project into my Eclipse IDE and launch it and debug it to see what it's doing.  The RCP Mail project works like a charm when I run it in my IDE.  It hides the UI just like I want my RCP app to do.

The main difference I've found so far is this.

When I run my application and try to use this code to get the Policy...

```
ProvisioningUI.getDefaultUI().getPolicy()
```

I get a different Policy then the one I registered with this code...

```
policy = new RestrictedP2UIPolicy();
policyRegistration = context.registerService(Policy.class.getName(), policy, null);
```

My ResrictedP2UIPolicy class is the same thing as the CloudPolicy class in the RCP Mail example application.

The Policy I get back at runtime is an implementation class called SDKPolicy.

Does anyone have any ideas why I'm getting this other Policy instead of the one I'm trying to register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK policy is coming from the p2.ui.sdk bundle. In an RCP application you shouldn't use this bundle as it provides the same p2 experience as the Eclipse SDK.

Comment: Ian, You were exactly right.  When I removed the p2.ui.sdk plugin from my RCP app, the correct behavior emerged.  But something unexpected happened as well.  I have a "Help" menu in my RCP application and I defined it in such a way that it would accept contributions from other plug-ins that were written for Eclipse.  When I removed the p2.ui.sdk plugin, it's menu contribution went away as expected, but then a new menu contribution arrived as if it was waiting for the p2.ui.sdk menu contribution to get out of the way.

Comment: The new menu contribution to the help menu is a menu folder labeled... "Software Updates"  and it has two commands in it... "Find and Install..." and "Manage Configuration..."    I used the plug-in spy to determine the plugin that is contributing the commands.  I removed it, but the menu folder remains and the commands are there in a disabled state as well.  Unfortunately, plug-in spy doesn't tell me which plug-in is contributing the menu folder.  I'd really like to remove this contribution to the Help menu in my RCP application.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I wonder if these are from the old update manager. Do you have any  update manager bundles installed?

Comment: I looked, and I realized that I'm not exactly sure how I would tell if I had any bundles from the old update manager installed.  What are the IDs for these bundles?